# How to disable the automatic saving and loading of the screen state by android when I return to my previously opened app?

Tags: android

If I multitask then when I leave my app the screen state is saved, and when I return to it the saved screen state is loaded. The problem is that only the screen state is loaded, the state variables in code are deleted, so there is a conflict between the screen state and application state.

Specific example: My app has two modes. In mode "A" the user can edit the size of an image, in mode "B" the user can edit the alpha of an image. The app starts in mode "A". Then the user switches to mode "B" and edits the alpha of the image. After this if the user leaves the app and then returns to it then the activity is automatically restarted and because of this the mode of the app becomes "A" (the default mode). But android applies the automatically saved alpha value set by the user in mode "B". In mode "A" there should be NEVER any alpha visible. If we are in mode "A" then I set

```
imgLeft.setAlpha(1f);
```

But this is overwritten by android with the saved screen state. So, how do I disable the automatic saving and loading of the screen state?

I want to write a custom screen state save and load. This was already a requested feature in my app, so there is no extra work from me. I just need android to stop interfering with my code.

Comment: Which part of the lifecycle are you running setAlpha? Before or after the state is loaded? Perhaps some more activity code could be helpful.

Comment: The setAlpha code is at onStart. And I don't load any state yet. The saved screen state is loaded automatially by android God knows when.

Comment: Is this an activity or a fragment? Try moving it to onResume(), if it's an activity.

Comment: The onResume did the trick. Thanks :)

Comment: Glad it helped. I posted it as an answer for you, for future reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's usually not worth it to write a custom save/restore state if you don't have to.

It is probably better, and easier, to run the `setAlpha(...)` code in the activity lifecycle *after* the state is restored. That way it will stay default Android restore code, but still allow you to restore the parts of the state that your code manually changes.

Assuming this is in an `Activity` (as opposed to a `Fragment` which has a different lifecycle), you should move this from the `onStart()` to the `onResume()` part of the lifecycle.

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    if (stateA) {
        imgLeft.setAlpha(1f);
    }
}
```